# Lazy loading problems with glassfish cluster and JPA

Tags: java, jpa, glassfish, cluster-computing, tapestry

I am having problems when I deploy my EAR to glassfish 3.1 cluster. 
The set-up is like this :
Cluster 1 on my host PC with 2 instances on 2 VM
Apache with mod_jk to load balance between the 2 instances (with sticky sessions)
Tapestry 4.x web app

So the problem is :

1. I hit my.domain.com
2. I am redirected to instance 1 (apache decides that will be instance 1 )
3. Log in
4. Shut down instance 1
5. Refresh the page
6. Apache will redirect me to instance 2

I am storing a JPA entity in the session (loginData) . The entity has some lazy loaded properties.
So when i am redirected to instance 2, i have an error saying :

```
Exception Description: An attempt was made to traverse a relationship using indirection         that had a null Session. 
This often occurs when an entity with an uninstantiated LAZY relationship is serialized and that lazy relationship is traversed after serialization. 
To avoid this issue, instantiate the LAZY relationship prior to serialization.
```

So what i am guessing is that at the time this object was serialized, the object was still not inflated with all the properties.

If i change to fetch=EAGER it all works as expected.

Changing to EAGER is not really an option tho...

Any ideas how to solve this issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Storing a JPA entity in your HttpSession is a bad idea. Restrict your entity lifetime to one HttpRequest and save yourself a lot of problems. Store the entity id in your session and use that to fetch your entity on each request. Potentially use JPA/Hibernate caching options to prevent a db hit every time.

In your situation this means that after login you'll store the @Id value of your entity in your HttpSession. Then when instance 2 tries to fetch the entity from the HttpSession it will just fetch the id and use that to fetch the actual entity within the scope of your refresh request.